# Nd4j INDArray from boolean to int

Tags: arrays, nd4j

If I have this array (its an INDArray but I'm simplifying the view)
`myArray = [[0, 0.7], [0, 0]]`, and I do this
`res = myArray.eq(0.7)`
I get `res = [[false, true], [false, false]]`

Is there a Nd4j method that can convert boolean INDArrays to 0/1 Arrays ? to get this `[[0, 1], [0, 0]]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In INDArray there’s cast method available, it will give you exactly what you want - array of 0s and 1s

Comment: Got it it's `res = res.castTo(DataType.INT)`